# How to use gnome-keyring in virt-manager / remote-viewer for decrypting an encrypted SSH key?

Tags: ssh, virt-manager

I use virt-manager to connect to a remote KVM/libvirt hypervisor over SSH. After connecting to the server, I can interact with machines just like if they were on my local computer (under the hood, SPICE is used).

However, since I have encrypted my SSH key, I have to enter the decryption password every time virt-manager connects to the hypervisor. For spice, there are like 7 connections, so I get the password prompt 7x every time I connect to the VM's display. Other people have described this madness as a "prompt loop" but it's just that SPICE has that many connections, and the connection works well after entering the password every time it asks for it.

For all other tools, such as regular ssh, I can use gnome-keyring, which prompts me for my keyring password once after logging in. I have enabled gcr-ssh-agent and added the passphrase to my encrypted SSH key to it, so whenever I use SSH, it simply asks the keyring for the password without any interaction with me.

Long story short, how can I direct virt-manager to use gnome-keyring to decrypt my SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

After long digging, I found the solution.

Symptoms: it would work when `virt-manager` was launched from the terminal, but not when launched from `dmenu` under i3 wm on xorg. This lead me to investigate into env variables and that brought the missing clue: my X-session does not know about the keyring.

Solution: Add the following line to `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK='/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
```

Note that you must replace the number 1000 by your user's ID (find out using the command `id`).